# SciTE: can't type tab character in makefile

Tags: tabs, scite

Some background: I used SciTE to edit my makefiles without issues until recently, when I changed the tab settings by adding these lines to `cpp.properties`:

```
tabsize=2
indent.size=2
use.tabs=0
```

And from I remember, everything still worked okay (I was editing both a makefile and a .cpp file).

That was about two weeks ago. Now I literally cannot type a tab character when editing a makefile, which requires a hard tab to work. Every tab character is turned into 4 spaces. (I search for "`\t`" and "    " to determine which is which.) Ironically, if I edit a .cpp file, I get an honest-to-goodness tab character (with a 4-space width) despite the settings above still in place. I have the lines below in my SciTEGlobal.properties, and I even added that to my `others.properties` and `SciTEUser.properties`, to no effect.

```
tabsize=4
indent.size=4
use.tabs=1
```

Wherenelse should I look? Something else is controlling my settings other than these files. Thanks.

**update** I've answered the question myself below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that adding tab settings in `<filetype>.properties` will have no effect. Only the `SciTEGlobal` and `SciTEUser` can take the settings. Since the former is meant to be left as default, the latter is the one you should edit. To tailor a tab setting to a specific file type, just add a `filepattern` modifier. For example, my `SciTEUser` file now has the following lines, and Scite is behaving the way I want it to.

```
# Tab
tabsize=4
tab.size.$(file.patterns.cpp)=2
indent.size=4
indent.size.$(file.patterns.cpp)=2
use.tabs=0
use.tabs.$(file.patterns.make)=1
tab.indents=1
tab.indents.$(file.patterns.make)=0
backspace.unindents=1
indent.automatic=1
tab.timmy.whinge.level=1
```

Credit goes to Laura Michaels for an informative writeup on this and much more: [SciTE Tips](http://www.distasis.com/cpp/scitetip.htm).